# Why am I seeing reference to a gemset of another project in my current project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, gemset

I recently created a new Rails project, and I believe I created a gemset for it before generating the app.

But when I encounter an error I get a message like this:

```
File /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@project_1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb
```

Even though I am in `project_2`. So in theory that should be `ruby-1.9.3-p194@project_2` and not `project_1`.

What can be causing this and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

P.S. I am using RVM.

**Edit 1:**

I ran `rvm gemset list` and this is the output:

```
project_2$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   project_1
=> project_2
   project_3
```

**Edit 2:**

I just ran `gem install rails` in my `project_2` directory after I created the `.rvmrc` file for that project after verifying that it is indeed using the gemset for that project specifically. However, when I generate the error again, I am still seeing a reference to the gemset in `project_1`.

**Edit 3:**

The output for `rvm current`:

```
$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p194@project_2
```

**Edit 4:**

Although, when I run `rvm current` in the same terminal window as my `rails s` I see:

```
$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p194@project_1
```

So how do I set the gemset across all terminal windows for right now, and in the future?

Comment: You're getting that output from `rvm gemset list` and you are still getting the `project1` error above?

Comment: @pferdefleisch Yes...I am still getting that error, even after I did what jim-stewart suggested in the answer below. By the way, I even restarted my server, so not sure what's happening.

Comment: what happens after you `gem install rails` and try to generate it again?

Comment: Generate what? My entire app? This is an existing app, that I am not in a hurry to re-generate if I don't have to. Is that the only solution?

Comment: I just re-ran `gem install rails` and then `bundle update rails` after changing the rails version from `3.2.8` to `3.2.9` in my `Gemfile`. But I am still getting the error from the gemset in a diff project.

Comment: @SeanHill Just updated the question with that output. Basically it is showing the gemset for `project_2`. Do I need to do something special - aside from restart my rails server to get it to "make the switch"?

Comment: Okay, so did you restart the app after you have switched your gemset?  Also, `rvm use` only applies to the current terminal session and future ones, but not to existing ones.  You will have to run `rvm use` on every open session or just reenter the directory with the .rvmrc.

Comment: @SeanHill Ok, I think I figured out the issue. I was using `rvm use` in a diff terminal window than my `rails s`. When I ran `rvm current` in the terminal window, I do see `ruby-1.9.3-p194@project_1`. How do I set the gemset across all terminal windows? Do I have to close all windows and restart them?

Comment: You can just run `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@project_2` in all of them.  Or, since you have created an `.rvmrc`, you can `cd ..` and `cd project_2`.  It will get reevaluated once you enter the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell RVM which gemset to use.  Try this:

```
rvm gemset use project_2
```

If that works, then you may wish to create a `.rvmrc` file in project_2's root directory so that it automatically switches to that gemset when you enter the directory:

```
cd /path/to/project_2
rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.3@project_2
```

That'll create a `.rvmrc` in `/path/to/project_2`.  `cd` out of the directory and back in, and it'll prompt you asking if you trust the `.rvmrc` file.  By default, it'll only ask you the first time.

**Edit:**

It is important to note that when creating a new `.rvmrc`, you need to `cd` out of the project directory in all open terminal sessions (including `rails s` and `rails console`). Otherwise the app will continue using the gemset from `project_1`.

Comment: That's the weird thing, I was already using the gemset for `project_2`. But I never had a `.rvmrc` in my `project_2` directory. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, even after I did this, I am still getting the error above. I also updated the question with what I see when I do `rvm gemset list`.